# MacOS Catalina not working on Samsung SSD from SATA

Tags: catalina, ssd, sata

I have MacBook Pro Mid 2012 whose HDD I replaced with SSD two years back and continue to work with High Sierra until I get end of support few months back.

So, I upgraded my OS to Catalina and since then it was working fine until few days back my system started hanging.

So, I tried reinstalling the OS again, but did not work. So, I finally erased the entire SSD and put a fresh installation from USB using my old HDD which was having Catalina at that time and tried to boot from USB itself which worked, but when I put the same SSD back in the laptop with SATA port, the same scenario of very slow boot and hang after that is coming.

My Laptop and SSD specs are as below:
SSD: V-Nand SSD 860 EVO 500GB
Laptop: MacBook Pro Mid 2012
Installed OS Catalina 10.15

1. Works fine (at bit slow due to HDD) in old HDD from SATA
2. Works fine using USB 3.0 SSD
3. Did not work with SSD on SATA port.

So can say, SATA port is fine and SSD as well but don't know both are not working together.

Comment: One difference between using the SSD by USB versus SATA would be USB probably does not support TRIM and SATA could support TRIM.

Comment: @DavidAnderson is there any possiblity I can use my SSD with sata? what should be the root cause.